# Como passo o valor da variável Tumb para meu controler?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Como passo o valor da variavel Thumb para meu controle? Os dois campos inputs então passando normalmente, porém a variavel tumb tem que passar a Url da Imagem do video.

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult SalvarItens(string titulo, string video_url, 
   string thumb) 
    {
        var item = new Dados_Video() 
        {
            Titulo = titulo,
            Thumb = thumb,
            UrlVideo = video_url
        };

            db.Dados_Video.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Minha View

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarItens", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { 
    @class ="form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})

           <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo"/>
           <input type="url" id="video-url" name="video_url"/>
           <input type="hidden" id="thumb" name="thumb"  />

           <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
        }
```

função Js

```
   function generateCode(url) {
        var video_id = url.split('v=')[1];
        var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
        if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
            video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
        }
        return video_id
    }

    function generateThumb(code) {
        return 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + code + '/1.jpg';
    }


     var thumb = generateThumb(generateCode(video_url));
```

Ajax Post

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $("#bt").on("click", function (event) {
            debugger;
            if (grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0) {

                var video_url = $('#video-url').val();
                var thumb = generateThumb(generateCode(video_url));
                var titulo = $('#titulo').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/SalvarItens",
                    data: { titulo: titulo, video_url: video_url, thumb: 
  thumb },
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "Json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.Resultado > 0) {

                        }
                    }
                });

                alert("Td certo");
            }
            else
                alert("Voce é um robo?");

        });


    });
```

Comment: SalvarItenss, é que eu dupliquei o controller e coloquei um s a mais nesse mais das duas maneiras o valor da thumb não vai, só o valor do titulo e da video_url, thumb sempre vai null

Answer (score 1):

Faça o post via Ajax poulando o objeto esperado, ou adicione um hidden field que irá armazenar o valor da thumb e o popule via JS

View

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarItenss", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { 
   @class ="form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})

       <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo"/>
       <input type="url" id="video-url" name="video_url"/>

       <input type="hidden" id="thumb" name="thumb" />

       <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
    }
```

Função Js

```
var thumb = generateThumb(generateCode(video_url));
document.getElementById("thumb").value = thumb;
```

Comment: o Valor está chegando nulo no controler, mais no ajax esta recebendo o valor

Comment: a variavel thumb recebe corretamente o valor , mais nao passa pro parametro do controler

Comment: Já inclui Leandro

Comment: A action é `SalvarItenss` ou `SalvarItens`? Você tem certeza de que está fazendo o post via ajax pelo `#bt` e não pelo  `<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />`, sem popular o hidden field `thumb`?

Comment: Sim, ele para no debbug do ajax e atribui os valores dos 3 campos, mais na controller só vai o valor dos do titulo e do video_url

Comment: então, atualize a pergunta com a sua view. pq em cada lugar diz que faz uma coisa diferente

Comment: Pronto atualizei ta identico agora.